# MSVS: How can I set the x64 as the default, instead of AnyCPU?

Tags: visual-studio, templates

MS Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

I create own project template. When I create a new project, based on my template, the default platform is `AnyCPU`:

[image]

But I need the `x64` (it exists too in this combobox) must to be default instead of `AnyCPU`.

Im my `csproj`-file settings I try to do this:

```
<!-- <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x64</Platform> -->
<Platform>x64</Platform>
```

Bot it doesn't help me. How can I set the `x64` in my template as the default, instead of `AnyCPU`?

Comment: Hey are you looking for this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547.aspx#configs

Comment: Yes, I read it, but the **Configurations** box keep own settings in the `*.v12.suo-file`. It is used by the `*.sln-file`. But I asked about the **project** template (not solution template). I.e. the project template has not that file.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the default platform is the **alphabetically first one**.

So for example if you have 2 platforms: Win32 and x64, the default will be Win32. But if you rename Win32 to x86, then x64 will be the default.

Source: https://aras-p.info/blog/2017/03/23/How-does-Visual-Studio-pick-default-config/platform/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this inside the csproj-file?

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x64</Platform>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Another option might be to remove the AnyCPU-entries from your csproj-file (if you don't need them at all).

Third option is to define x64 in the configuration manager of the solution.